# Individual queries don't match overall query

Tags: sql

I will try to be as descriptive as possible, but it it may still be a little vague.  Anyway, here it goes.

The data consists of 64 variables and millions of observations.
The important variables within the 64 are:
Call_ID, Phone_Number, Risk_Score, Fraud_Status, and EntryTimestamp

For each individual call, there can be multiple risk scores, fraud statuses, and entry timestamps, but there can only be one call ID and one phone number.

The different fraud statuses are: 
1. ''
2. 'Fraud'
3. 'Genuine'
4. 'Unknown'
5. 'Inconclusive'

So I want to write a query to count all unique calls with each of the above fraud statuses and with a Risk_Score < 80 and EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000'.  In other words, I want to count all unique calls that happened before 4/20/2018 at 5PM that have a fraud status of '' and a Risk_Score < 80,
then I want to count all unique calls that happened before 4/20/2018 at 5PM that have a fraud status of 'Fraud' and a Risk_Score < 80, and so on.

I thought the following would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score AS 
      FLOAT) < 80 AND Fraud_Status = ''
```

Lead to 2,732,453 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score 
      AS FLOAT) < 80 AND Fraud_Status = 'Fraud'
```

Lead to 1,007 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score 
      AS FLOAT) < 80 AND Fraud_Status = 'Genuine'
```

Lead to 1,659 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score 
      AS FLOAT) < 80 AND Fraud_Status = 'Unknown'
```

Lead to 3,433 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score AS 
      FLOAT) < 80 AND Fraud_Status = 'Inconclusive'
```

Lead to 30 rows

Total Rows: 2,732,453 + 1,007 + 1,659 + 3,433 + 30 = 2,738,582

but the combined total number of rows for all of these queries do not add up to the rows in the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call_ID
FROM DATA
WHERE EntryTimestamp < '2018-04-20 18:00:00.000' AND CAST(Risk_Score AS 
      FLOAT) < 80
```

Lead to 2,733,076 rows

which should contain the rows of all the previous queries.  Does anyone know why this method wouldn't work?
Please let me know if you need more information.  Thank you!

Comment: can fraud status be NULL? what's the output of "select distinct Fraud_Status  from DATA" ?

Comment: Hello Mitch, the output is:
1.
2. Fraud
3. Genuine
4. Inconclusive
5. Unknown

There are not any NULL values in this column.

Comment: You are counting distinct ids.  Some `call_ids` match more than one condition.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff.  After think about your comment for a while, it finally clicked! It's the last query that is wrong for finding the total calls.  I should trust the sum of all the individual queries for the total number of calls with a risk_score < 80.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting distinct ids. Some call_ids match more than one condition. – Gordon Linoff

Thank you @GordonLinoff. After think about your comment for a while, it finally clicked! It's the last query that is wrong for finding the total calls. I should trust the sum of all the individual queries for the total number of calls with a risk_score < 80.0.